# Mediaelement.js hover timestamp

Tags: php, wordpress, mediaelement.js

I am using mediaelement.js to play Audio in my Wordpress site. I'm having trouble getting it to function exactly like the player on the front page of the [mediaelementjs site](http://mediaelementjs.com).  Particularly, I want to add timestamps when the user hovers over the audio player so that they can more easily navigate to a particular time. The player is working fine otherwise.

A second, related question. Has anyone found an easy way to add links to particular time stamps in this player (e.g. clicking **1:00** would cause the video to jump to that place without reloading the page). I tried the plugin "Skip to timestamp" but could not get the shortcodes to execute properly within my PHP template.

Sorry I don't have any code up live yet. Here is the code to generate the player.

```
$attr = array(
                    'src'      => 'myfilepath',
                    'loop'     => '',
                    'autoplay' => '',
                    'preload' => 'none',
                    'features' => array('playpause','progress','current','duration','volume')
                );
                echo wp_audio_shortcode( $attr );
```